# Is it correct to say "more sufficient"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> I suggest that the maintenance period be from 12:30 to 2:30 so that we can have *more sufficient* time to handle if any unexpected problems occur.

Is it correct to say *more sufficient*?

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to say *more sufficient* in this sentence (if any).

[*Sufficient*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sufficient) is an adjective which means *being as much as is needed; enough to meet a need or purpose; adequate.*

It doesn't make any sense to say "more enough". Enough is enough. You can say *more than enough*, *more than adequate*, or *more than sufficient* if you want to stress giving yourself a large margin of time.

> ...so that we have sufficient time to handle any unexpected problems *that may* occur.
>   ...so that we can have more/enough/adequate time to handle any unexpected problems...
>   ...so that we can have more than enough time to handle any unexpected problems...

The Free Dictionary.com

Comment: +1. I don't expect to see a more satisfactory answer to the OP's question than this one.

Comment: [more sufficient; most sufficient] http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sufficient

Comment: -1 making sense out of English expressions often fails (English is not logic); and changing the word being asked about (sufficient > enough) changes the expression.

Answer (score -2):

"More" is a relative term

"Sufficient" is a relative term

Therefore, saying "more sufficient" is the same as saying something is relatively relative...it does not correlate any real meaning.

Comment: This is incorrect. The trouble is exactly that _sufficient_ is **not** a relative term, but an absolute, binary one. Something is either sufficient or not sufficient. _More_ only makes sense with relative terms.

Comment: [more sufficient; most sufficient] http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sufficient